# AEM 6.0: Pass dynamic value to clientlibs @categories

Tags: aem, sightly, htl

I am trying to pass dynamic value while calling clientlibs to @ categories using HTL but it is not picking the value.

Snippet of code:

```
<sly data-sly-use.config="com.demo.core.sightly.page.Config">
    <sly data-sly-use.clientLib="${'/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html'}">
        <js data-sly-call="${clientLib.js @ categories='${config.clientLibFolder}'}"></js>
    </sly>
</sly>
```

While I am printing the value `${config.clientLibFolder}` it is coming.

Is there any way I can pass dynamic value to @categories while calling clientlibs.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax appears to be wrong. Did you try

```
<js data-sly-call="${clientLib.js @ categories=config.clientLibFolder}"></js>
```

Or

```
<js data-sly-call="${clientLib.js @ categories=[config.clientLibFolder]}"></js>
```